# The element is already the child of another element in TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am working on Silverlight and in a very strange problem where it do not give any exception and do not break on running at breakpoints.
So i kept a break point in app.xaml.cs at

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
 //something here
}
```

On debugging it break and i found that in "e" i have following unhandled exception:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: The element is already the child of another element. 
    to MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult (UInt32 hr) 
    to MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue (IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh) 
    to MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue (IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj) 
    to System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore (DependencyProperty dp, Object value) 
    to System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue (DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry & newEntry, Object newValue) 
    to System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue (DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry & newEntry, ValueOperation operation) 
    to System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression (DependencyProperty dp) 
    System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget to () 
    System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired to () 
    to System.Windows.Data.Binding.EnsureBreakPoint (BindingDebugState debugState, Action callback, Boolean canDelay) 
    to System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(Object sender, e DataContextChangedEventArgs) 
    to System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged (Object sender, e DataContextChangedEventArgs) 
    to System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged (DataContextChangedEventArgs e) 
    to System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnTreeParentUpdated (DependencyObject newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive) 
    to System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateTreeParent (IManagedPeer oldParent, IManagedPeer newParent, bIsNewParentAlive Boolean, Boolean keepReferenceToParent) 
    to MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate (oldParentElement IntPtr, IntPtr parentElement, IntPtr childElement, bIsParentAlive Byte, Byte bKeepReferenceToParent, Boolean canCreateParent)}
```

**Now when it happens :**

I have `TabControl` which has 3 Tab Items.
One Tabitem show xml code, second show c# code and **the third (the Nasty one) shows UI elements created dynamically using c#.**

Now the above TabControl (which already contains 3 TabItems) is stored as Content of another TabItem(result here in my code below) like this which is kind of parent of all.

(so you can see that first is "Result" then it contains "TabControl" and then it contains "3 TabItems")
And this `result` is stored in  `ObservableCollection<TabItem> result = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();` **I mean it will have two tabitem like result**. And each of my "result" in this collection is responsible for rendering informations of different object in the given three tab items(xml, code and UI elemnts rendering in Tabitem correspoding to selected result(tabitem) in this ObservableCollection list).

**When problem occurs ? :**

The problem occurs only when i switch from one result TabItem to another and then come back to the same "TabItem" (which is responsible for UI element rendering, **Please note that it happens for this TabItem Only, Not other two**) (Only for the third TabItem of `Result` which i called "nasty" one, Which is supposed to be rendered UI Elements created dynamically).**it crashes my project and gives that Unhandled exception**

**Could some one please let me know the cause of this problem with solution ? Thanks a lot.**

EDIT : (please see in explain to avoid confusion)

Suppose i have two "Result" tabitems in my observable collection of TabItem and each "Result" represent different object and renders different UI element on clicking 3rd TabItem of the TabControl of each Result(TabItem). At start when i click the 3rd TabItem (nasty one, which Ui elemnts) of first "Result"it works fine now again i click on 3rd tab item of of second "Result" it still works fine and render UI elemnt  replacing the first one.and now when second time when i click back to the 3rd  TabItem of First "Result" then it carshes (I mean first i Clicked 3 rd tabitem of first Result then i clicked to 3rd TabItem of second Result, Until it worked fine and render two different UI elemnts on different click at same place  but **nowx when i go back to 3rd tabtem of first Result , It crashes the application with that exception**)

Note: Please nOtethat i have done the binding of these three TabItems in c# dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a strange problem, it's a really common one. Furthermore, the error message really couldn't be too much clearer:

```
The element is already the child of another element.
```

Each UI element in WPF can only be used in the UI in one place at one time. We can move them around, or remove them from one location and add them to another location, but we *cannot add the same element in two places at once*.

Therefore (without looking through all of your code), I can only assume that you have attempted to use an object that already exists in the UI in your dynamically created `TabControl`. Once you find the offending element, swap it with a new element, perhaps after copying the values from the used element. After doing that, you should have more luck with displaying your third `TabItem`.

Comment: @Sherdin thanks but i guess you still couldnt understnd the problem. please see the edit part i have explained properly my problem .

Comment: No, I understand that error perfectly well and I have explained why you are getting it. There is only one reason that that `Exception` is thrown and my answer explains the cause. You should be able to work out your own fix with this information.

Comment: @Sherdin i say this because on second time click to 3 rdtabitem(to render UI element) it do not work but when i see the other two tabs "xml rendering" and "code rendering" they still renders but rendering again second time of first Result's" 3rd TabItem (after redering of second's Result's 3 rd TabItem do not work). I mean  each Result renders information of different object (not same).

Comment: I mean by both "Result" (TabItem) renders information of different objects but at same place. And on clicking once they works fine. Theu renders UI at same place replacing the previous one. But on re rendering the UI element of first "Result" after the second one creates  that problem.

Comment: You can ignore the facts as much as you like, but if you are getting this error, then *somewhere in your code*, you have tried to add an element into the UI that already exists in the UI. Fact!

Comment: i am agree from you. But Do you think it is because when i re-render the same UI element at same place (after switching to the second one, I mean First->Second->First (crash)) ? Please let me know if i am correct ?

Comment: In Visual Studio, press Ctrl+Alt+E to open the *Exceptions* dialog and make sure that the *User-unhandled* check boxes are ticked. This error *should* break on the line that contains the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60022/discussion-between-user3735822-and-sheridan).

Comment: please see in the chat room i have uploaded some snapshots